# JQM 1.4 fixed footer not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an Android application with JQM 1.4 which is being wrapped with PhoneGap 3.3. The problem I am having is the footer does not display. The header? no problem at all.
Here is one of the pages from my `index.html`:

```
<div data-role="page" id="eventPage"> <!-- Start Event Page -->
    <div data-role="header" id="mainhead" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <div class="ui-btn-left" id="home"><a href="#home"><img src="img/Home.png" width="25" height="25"/></a></div>
            <h1 id="event-title">Title of Mobile App</h1>
     <div id="backevent" class="ui-btn-right"><a href="#" onClick="previous_event()"><img src="img/backbtn.png" width="25" height="25"/></a></div>
     <div id="nxtevent" class="ui-btn-right"><a href="#" target="_blank" onClick="next_event()"><img src="img/NextBtn.png" width="25" height="25"/></a></div>


    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="page-title"></div>
        <div id="page-region"></div>
        <a href="#" onClick="Calendar_Add()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Add to Calendar</a>
        <div id="page-content"></div>

    </div> 

    <div id="eventFooter" data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div><!-- End eventPage -->
```

I started by adding the `data-position="fixed"` to the footer which did not work.

I then tried:

```
#eventFooter {  
    background:#0B436F;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute
}
```

which did not work, so I tried `position:fixed` in place of `position:absolute` which also did not work.

I find it strange that the header displays correctly with no error but the footer does not with identical coding? Any suggestions?

SOLUTION:

I took the advise of Omar and upgraded to JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 and modified my code to this

```
<div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1></h1>
</div>
```

and my CSS to this -color doesn't matter just listing so you know to remove anything else.

```
#footer {   
    background:#0B436F;
    color:#FFF; 
}
```

Seems to work just fine now.

Comment: try latest version of jQM 1.4.2, there is a workaround for fixed toolbars on Android.

Comment: @Omar I will give this a try. Are the workarounds tough to find? or sitting in the documentation?

Comment: You have nothing to do but using 1.4.2, it will take care of it.

Comment: OKay files have been updated. Still the same result :/

Comment: Weird, check GitHub https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/fixedToolbar.workarounds.js

Comment: i tested in web working fine.

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/B6TgZ/55/

Answer (score 0):

Unless your code is above incomplete you need to add some more params with position absolute:

```
#eventFooter {  
    background:#0B436F;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I give this a try with no luck. It is probably an issue with JQM then. Thanks for responding though!